# Kubuntu freezing for no apparent reason - xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2594]

Tags: kde, freeze, kubuntu

Kubuntu is crashing on seemingly random occasions about once a week.

After a crash

```
journalctl -b -1 -e
```

shows the following events:

```
xdg-desktop-portal-kde[2594]: xdp-kde-background: GetAppState called: no parameters
```

every 30 seconds. I suppose this derives from the unresponsive OS.

To me, it seems to be connected to using Wayland. /var/crash has no associated .crash file.
Which log files should I look further into, to resolve the problem?

Thanks a lot!